# The Google Maps Platform server rejected your request. Invalid request. Invalid 'size' parameter

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I have a link to google street view in a web mapping app that is tied to a dynamic address attribute {SitusAddress}

The link is embedded as an img src to the same location but as a small image on the web page

```
img src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=270x150&location=${SitusAddress}&fov=120&pitch=-5
```

notice the size parameter at 270x150. This makes a rather small image. When the image is clicked, I want a nother tab to open with the same street view but in google maps taking up the entire page such as what would happen if uyou were in google maps and clicked street view. I tried it without a size parameter and with size =100%x100%

```
<hr><a href=https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=100%x100%&location=${SitusAddress} target='_blank'>
```

How can I fulfill the size param that's not a static size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dynamically calculate the size of the image needed in pixels and provide that pixel based size to the API.

Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro#required-parameters) size is required and is in pixels:

- size specifies the output size of the image in pixels. Size is specified as {width}x{height} - for example, size=600x400 returns an image 600 pixels wide, and 400 high.